# "President" or "Chairman" of a (thesis examining) committee?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I am wondering what is the difference between "President" and "Chairman" of a committee.

As far as I got it, a "president" is a more honorary position when "chairman" is rather executive. Is this correct?
What is the most widespead/idiomatic title to name the head of a thesis examining committee? (There is no guideline given by my university in this regard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that in the US the person responsible for a dissertation committee's paperwork is usually a *chair*, because *chair* is usually the title of the person who heads any *committee*.

There is no difference inherent in the designations *president* and *chair* , though of course the duties of the position may vary different institutions. In fact, *president* and *chairman* employ the same metaphor: *presidents* are etymologically, the persons who "sit in front of" the body over which they preside, occupying the "chair" set aside for that position. But it's only a metaphor: for my own dissertation orals we sat in a small classroom at desks drawn into a circle. And the "chair" was ex officio my dissertation advisor.